# After 90 days ESTA exhaustion in the US as a German, when can I come back?

Tags: usa, esta

I am from Germany and got accepted for an 90 days ESTA. Assumed I will stay 90 days in the US. When can I get into the country again via ESTA? (I assume that the ESTA will be not the problem but the border protection. It really depends on what the reason is for what I am entering the US, right?)

Comment: Your ESTA authorization should be valid for two years (or until your passport expires if that is sooner).  The maximum duration of a single stay is 90 days (or shorter under some circumstances).

Comment: ESTA is not an authorization to enter in US, and it has some conditions (else you should apply for the relative visa). So it depends why do you enter to US, and what the immigration officer assumes (she/he must presume you will immigrate illegally, by law, so the proof is on your side). If you are coming back every 90 days, it will be suspicious (but if you have good reasons).

Comment: Note that if you spend more than 183 days of a year in the US you might have to pay taxes.